# Is there a way to do nested generic constraints in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Say that I have the following classes:

```js
   abstract class Id { ... }
   abstract class Entity<TId extends Id>{ ... }
   class ProductId extends Id { ... }
   class ProductEntity extends Entity<ProductId> { ... }
```

and I wanted to create a class by doing:

```js
class GenericRepository<TEntity extends Entity<TId extends Id>> {
    update(entity: TEntity): void { ... }
    get(id: TId): TEntity { ... }
}
```

Is this possible without doing something like:

```js
class GenericRepository<TEntity extends Entity<TId>, TId extends Id> {
    update(entity: TEntity): void { ... }
    get(id: TId): TEntity { ... }
}
```

to be able to call:

```js
const foobar = new GenericRepository<ProductEntity>();
```

instead of:

```js
const foobar = new GenericRepository<ProductEntity, ProductId>();
```

and for it to somehow constrain the value for both `Entity` and `Id`?

In other words, I need to have a nested constraint.

Comment: I don't understand... is `FooBar` itself not supposed to be generic? Neither of your two examples would compile... you could write `class FooBar<U extends SomeClass> extends Foo<Bar<U>> {}` or `class FooBar<T extends Bar<U>, U extends SomeClass> extends Foo<T> {}` but in both cases, `FooBar` is generic in something.  Note that your example types are *too* minimal, since `SomeClass`, `Foo<string>`, `Bar<number>`, and `Foo<number>` are [all the same type](https://tsplay.dev/mx6YGw), namely `{}`.  Please add some structure to them so the compiler doesn't treat them all as the empty object type.

Comment: For example, [this](https://tsplay.dev/N53e9W) would be enough to distinguish them.  See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at-- and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--

Comment: This seems a bit like asking how to make this function `function foo(t) { bar(t, u) }` get a value for `u`, but somehow without adding a second argument to `foo`. I might help to show how you expect this to be used, then maybe we can clarify what a better approach might be.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I've updated the question based on the feedback.